# Comparison between SOAP and XML RPC

Tags: asp.net

I was reading the comparison between SOAP and XML-RPC from the following article.
http://weblog.masukomi.org/writings/xml-rpc_vs_soap.htm

In the article it is mentioned that SOAP can:

1).Can specify recipient

2).Require client understanding

3).Message specific processing instructions

Can some one please explain the above mentioned points with example?.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

http://r4r.co.in/webservice/01/tutorial/basic/soap.shtml